# Is there a symbol for antiparallel?

Tags: notation, vectors

I've been doing some work where I've needed to talk about vectors that are parallel and those that are antiparallel, parallel to the negative of the other vector.

Is there a symbol for this?

I can write $A\parallel B$ for parallel, $A \not\parallel B$ for not parallel. Is there a symbol for writing antiparallel without having to write $A\parallel-B$ ?

.

Edit: this is of use in physics, where, for instance, you can talk about spins which are parallel (both up or down) and spins which are antiparallel (one up and one down).

Comment: I think $A\parallel -B$ is by far the most appealing intuitively and notationally. It meshes with the traditional use of $\parallel$ and it's easy to justify it as an extension.

Comment: And by the way, if you're writing with latex, you should use `\parallel` and `\nparallel`. It'd be more consistent with latex style.

Comment: Wait, we use double vertical bars or double slashes for the notation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you should consider using a symbol that shows your meaning of "parallelism". Could try these two couple:
$v \mathrel{{{\upharpoonleft}{\downharpoonright}}} w$ or $v\mathrel{\uparrow\downarrow}w$ as opposite to positively-parallel: $v\mathrel{{{\upharpoonleft}{\upharpoonright}}}w$ or $v\mathrel{\uparrow\uparrow}w$
Hope it helps

Comment: Really like the opposing harpoons. Could nudge them closer together with a `\!`, $v \upharpoonleft \! \downharpoonright w$

Comment: I tried to make them stay closer, but I didn't get how to do

Comment: `\!` is a thin negative space. So the full sequence for the snugged-up $\upharpoonleft \! \downharpoonright$ is `\upharpoonleft \! \downharpoonright`

Comment: Thanks, it can be useful. However consider using \mathrel to get the right spacing outside the two harpoons new symbol

Comment: I like this proposed symbol (especially the harpoons), but it may be worth reminding readers to define the notation when they use it - don't count on people to understand or guess what it means.

Comment: @DavidZ This notation is standard in Russian literature (at least, used to be), see https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C

Comment: I'm Italian, I swear :D but nice to discover it

Comment: @Joker_vD Ah, well in that case there'd be no need to explain it, if the audience is expected to be familiar with it already.

Answer (score 17):

I belive that when we talk about vectors you can use $a \uparrow\uparrow b$  for parallel vectors and $a \uparrow\downarrow b$ for antiparallel.

Comment: And in mathematics, $a \uparrow\uparrow b$ for a really big number.

Comment: @Neil And $a \uparrow\uparrow\uparrow b$  for a really, really big number.

Comment: @JAB And a $a\uparrow \uparrow \uparrow \uparrow b$ for a really, really, really big number.

Comment: They should call $\uparrow$ the "really operator".

Comment: @JakeRobb Then is ↓ the "really not operator" or the "not really operator"?

Comment: @ashkan related ELU question: ["It doesn't really matter" v "it really doesn't matter"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/414675/80007)

Comment: That's what we have used in school and university for showing that vectors are antiparallel.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Is the terminal symbol of the Bigbiggerbiggest language, $\mathbb{B}$, so $\uparrow\in\mathbb{B}$ and it is called "big". Now we introduce the successor function $\sigma:\mathbb{B}\longrightarrow\mathbb{B}$ from the languages to itself. We can certainly, by a little abuse of notation, write $\uparrow$ instead of $\sigma$. So we get the so-called Bigbiggerbiggest language. A language 10-yo boys and girls know very well for explaining how they are $\{\text{more}\}\times\{\text{clever},\text{strong},\text{funny},\dots\}$

Answer (score 10):

There isn't such a symbol (as far as I know) because if $v\|w$ then $-v\|w$ as well. Indeed each vector is parallel to its own opposite, as you take only the line on which it lies, when you speak of direction.
(To describe that fact you however can write $v\in\mathbb{R}^{-}w$ in an opposite way of "positive" parallelism:$v\in\mathbb{R}^+w$)

Comment: +1, but still, for the purposes of a talk or paper, it would seem acceptable to define parallelism and antiparallelism of rays, thinking of vectors as rays, and extend the classical notation. (Being clear that one is doing so, of course.) If $v$ and $w$ are vectors, and we consider them "parallel" if they lie in parallel lines, one is already doing a bit of interpretation

Comment: Consider vector A as a ray going from point u to v. If vector B goes from point v to u, then it is antiparallel to A.

Answer (score 1):

The "hat" symbol denotes a unit vector pointing in the original vector's direction https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector

So if you say $\hat{A}=-\hat{B}$, then that means that the vectors are in opposite directions. You could also say that A and -B are parallel.